# How to store an object in a vector when the object contains a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, game-development

I have been learning C++ for about a month, and I want to make a little game to practice. I have created a class `Character` that has a `unique_ptr` to a `Weapon` object.

The issue is that, when I try to `push_back()` the `Character` into a `vector` of `Character`s named `_players`, it causes an error because of the unique_ptr:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

Character::Character(weaponName,int weaponRange,int weaponDamage)
{
    //_weapon is a unique_pointer in the .hpp
    _weapon = std::make_unique<Weapon>(weaponName,weaponRange,weaponDamage);                
}

std::vector<Character> _players;

void addPlayer(Character character)
{
    _players.push_back(character);
}

int main()
{
    addPlayer(Character());
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried creating the `Character` object in the `main()` function, then passing it with or without reference to `addPlayer()`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Character player;
    addPlayer(player);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find a solution without having to use a `vector` of pointers, because I have been told that it might not be the fastest option.

Comment: The first, biggest question is why a player has a pointer to a weapon instead of just having a weapon. Or given that a person might carry more than on weapon, a `std::vector` of weapons. But either way, why involve pointers at all?

Comment: @JerryCoffin you are right, I wanted to practice with smart pointers and pass the unique pointer from player to player but we can just make a copy to the other player and avoid using pointers to make the coding easier.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
void addPlayer(Character character)
{
    _players.push_back(character);
}
```

is passed a copy of the character object. And by copying the object, you are also copying its contents. Inside the object lies the **_weapon** field, which you have just initialised to a unique pointer. As the name implies, unique pointers cannot be copied, which makes the entire object's cloning fail.

What is commonly done in C++ is to instead pass a reference as the function's argument, which will behave like a pointer (thus not copying the entire object but just its address), however it differs a bit, mostly in that you don't have to pass a pointer: you pass it like you already do, and what changes is only the function's definition.

To do this, just redefine the function like so:

```
void addPlayer(Character& character)
{
    _players.push_back(character);
}
```